# Data used by several usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a page with several different usercontrols.
All of them run the following code:

```
var member = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
MemberProfile mp = MemberProfile.GetUserProfile(member.UserName);
string affilID = mp.GetPropertyValue("aID").ToString();
```

I would like to get this value once and save it for use with all the controls.
I'm not sure where in the life cycle I need to do this to insure it is accessible to all the controls when they are being rendered.
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in the Page_Load event with Session?  Maybe something like this (C#):

```
MembershipUser member;
MemberProfile mp;
string affilID; 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["member"] != null)
    {
        member = (MembershipUser)Session["member"];
    }
    else
    {
        member = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
    }

    if (Session["mp"] != null)
    {
        mp = (MemberProfile)Session["mp"];
    }
    else
    {
        mp = MemberProfile.GetUserProfile(member.UserName);
    }

    if (Session["affilID"] != null)
    {
        affilID = (string)Session["affilID"];
    }
    else
    {
        affilID = mp.GetPropertyValue("aID").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just flip it around and check for the affilID first. If I have it, I don't need the rest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it's all on the same page, as long as it's outside of a subroutine you should be able to use it within any subroutine. Or am I missing something?